# How can I make custom color in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(foo6, aes(x=area, y=fd, colour = id)) + geom_point()

id         lon        lat         area          fd              tp          rt    
West    -109.3906   48.57889    349.6484    5.500000e+01    5.00000000  50.0000000
West    -109.3906   48.57889    349.6484    1.775000e+01    5.00000000  12.7500000
```

There are four different kinds of IDs. Right now the plot takes the colors automatically. But I would like to mention the colors each ID takes myself. Could you please explain how to do it?

Best

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_manual.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(foo6, aes(x=area, y=fd, colour = id)) + geom_point() + 
   scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
```